# Prove Liouville theorem without using mean value property

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, elliptic-pde

How can I prove the following Liouville theorem without using the mean value property?

> If $u$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla u|^2 dx \leq C$ for some $C > 0$, then $u$ is constant.

The proof that I know indeed uses the mean value property for harmonic functions.

---

From the comments: is it rigorous to do it like this: $-\Delta u = 0 \implies \int_{\mathbb R^n} |\nabla u|^2 = 0$ (integrating by parts, hence $u$ is constant? It seems to easy, probably I'm missing something.

Comment: If you are comfortable with tempered distributions and Fourier transform, you can write a short proof of a much more general fact: any harmonic tempered distribution $u$ is a (harmonic) polynomial. Indeed, $u$ being harmonic implies $|\xi|^2 \hat u(\xi)$ being equal to zero, which easily implies that $\hat u$ is a distribution supported at $\{0\}$, thus the Fourier transform of a polynomial.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you! This is very interesting. But actually I'd like to avoid the Fourier transform too in the proof.

Comment: You could use the Bochner formula and integration by parts to show the Hessian of $u$ identically vanishes.  This means $u$ is affine and hence constant.

Comment: @RBega2 You mean using $-\Delta u = 0 \implies \int_{\mathbb R^n} |\nabla u|^2 = 0$ and then $u = constant$? Is this rigorous? Where is the boundedness assumption above used?

Comment: The suggested Bochner formula states that $\Delta \lvert Du \rvert^2 = 2 \lvert D^2 u \rvert^2$ for a harmonic function $u$. You could then for example integrate this against a suitable sequence of test functions $(\varphi_i \mid i \in \mathbf{N})$. In this approach the assumed bound would be used via a Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @Lao I should have clarified that you integrate against suitable test functions as Leo Moos describes.

Comment: @LeoMoos Thank you! Could you add some details about this in an answer? Also, can you point a mistake about the other identity in my comment above?

Comment: @RBega2 Thank you!

Comment: @Lao The problem with your comment is that you forgot the boundary term in your integration by parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below we will prove, by purely energy methods, the following sharper statement: Let $u$ be a harmonic function which satisfies $$\liminf_{r \to \infty} \frac1{r^2} \frac{1}{|B_r|}\int_{B_r} |u|^2 = 0.$$ Then $u$ is constant.

All Liouville theorems of this sort are soft/qualitative versions of harder/more quantitative regularity statements. In this case, the Liouville statement follows from the interior gradient $L^\infty$ bound for harmonic functions (as we will see below). So another version of your question could be: Is there an energy methods proof of the interior $L^\infty$ bound for harmonic functions which in particular does not use the mean value property?

The classical energy methods proof of the pointwise estimates for harmonic functions uses only two ingredients: the Caccioppoli inequality (the most basic energy estimate), and the Sobolev inequality (because you have to get pointwise bounds from $L^2$ bounds somehow!).

The Caccioppoli inequality says that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{B_r}
|\nabla u|^2
\leq 
\frac{C}{r^2} \int_{B_{2r}}  u^2 \,.
\end{equation*}
You get this by testing the equation with $\varphi^2u$ where $\varphi$ is an appropriate cutoff function.

Iterating the Caccioppoli inequality many times, we get
\begin{equation*}
\int_{B_r} |\nabla^k u|^2
\leq 
\frac{C}{r^{2k}} \int_{B_{2^kr}} u^2 \,.
\end{equation*}
If $k > 1+\frac d2$, then we can the Sobolev inequality to get
\begin{equation*}
\| \nabla u \|_{L^\infty(B_r)}^2 
\leq 
\frac{C}{r^2} 
\frac{1}{|B_r|}
\int_{B_{2^kr}} u^2\,.
\end{equation*}
Now send $r\to \infty$ along a good subsequence for the liminf, and you discover that $\nabla u=0$, which means $u$ is constant.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more thorough write up of my comment.

Fix a non-negative smooth function $\phi$ which is identically $1$ on $B_1$ and vanishes identically outside $B_2$.  Pick $M$ so $|\Delta \phi| \leq M$.   Set $\phi_R(x)=\phi(x/R)$.  We have $|\Delta \phi_R(x)|\leq M/R^2$.

By the Bochner identity
$$
\Delta \frac{1}{2} |\nabla u|^2= \nabla u \cdot \nabla \Delta u + |\nabla^2 u|^2=|\nabla^2 u|^2
$$

We have
$$
\int_{B_R} |\nabla^2 u|^2\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi_R |\nabla^2 u|^2=\frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi_R \Delta |\nabla u|^2\leq \frac{M}{2R^2} \int_{B_{2R}} |\nabla u|^2 \leq \frac{CM}{2 R^2}.
$$
Sending $R\to \infty$ implies $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla^2 u|^2=0$ so $\nabla^2 u$ vanishes identically.

This means $u(x)=\mathbf{a}\cdot x +b$ but finite energy forces $\mathbf{a}=0$.

Comment: Thank you. Two questions: (1) At which point was the assumption $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla u|^2 dx \leq C$ used? (2) Why the simpler observation $-\Delta u = 0 \implies \int_{\mathbb R^n} |\nabla u|^2 = 0$ does not work?

Comment: (1): Errr... finite energy was used when RBega writes "finite energy forces"! (2) try $u(x)=x$ in dimension 1. Surely your "proof" is wrong!

Comment: @leomonsaingeon (1) Thank you: I missed the last line. (2) Indeed it must be wrong, but I cannot pinpoint the flaw: do you see where the mistake is?

Comment: @Lao: well, for us to try pinpointing your mistake you must first give us your proof! But this is a classical mistake, in fact: you cannot integrate by parts in the whole space, that's all

Comment: @leomonsaingeon Why can't you integrate by parts in the whole space in this case?

Comment: A priori you can only integrate by parts on bounded sets, say balls. When you do so you have a non-zero term on the boundary, and this term does not vanish when the radius of the ball $R\to+\infty$ unless $\nabla u$ (actually $\partial_r u$) decays at infinity (which is precisely what the "finite energy" assumption guarantees, in some weak sense)

Comment: @leomonsaingeon I see, but I'm still a bit confused: isn't it very common in PDE books to integrate by parts in the whole space and neglect boundary terms when the involved functions are in $L^1$?

Comment: @leomonsaingeon And if we consider the test functions as in the answer above, could it be possible to consider the quantity $\int \phi_R |\nabla u|^2 $ instead of the one with the hessian?

Comment: Sure, but the problem remains that you will not get rid of the boundary term on $\partial B_R$. The whole point of the exercise is precisely showing that if $\nabla u\in L^2$ then this remainder decays to zero as $R\to\infty$.

Comment: @leomonsaingeon The boundary term in this case is $\int_{\partial B} \partial_\nu u \phi_R u$ How can you show that this satisfies the decay?

Comment: @Lao  I used finite energy twice.  First, for the final inequality in the string of inequalities and secondly to rule out affine functions.

Comment: @RBega2 Thank you! What do you think about the discussion above regarding using $\int \phi_R |\nabla u|^2$ instead of the hessian and estimating the boundary term $\int_{\partial B} \partial_{\nu} u \phi_R u$?

Comment: @Lao That would be easiest if $u$ was in $L^2$.  This is in general not true (e.g. a constant function) so the argument gets more involved.  It's possible that playing around with the Poincare inequality would work.

Comment: @RBega2 Thank you. I'm trying unsuccessfully to do this and posted it as a separate question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381087/alternative-proof-of-liouville-theorem-for-harmonic-functions