# Alternative proof of Liouville theorem for harmonic functions

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, regularity

From [Prove Liouville theorem without using mean value property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380958/prove-liouville-theorem-without-using-mean-value-property) the following question arises:
To prove the Liouville theorem

> If $u$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\nabla u|^2 dx \leq C$ for some $C > 0$, then $u$ is constant.

is it possible to use the following reasoning?

> Fix a non-negative smooth function $\phi$ which is identically $1$ on $B_1$ and vanishes identically outside $B_2$.  Pick $M$ so $|\Delta \phi| \leq M$.   Set $\phi_R(x)=\phi(x/R)$.  We have $|\nabla \phi_R(x)|\leq M/R$ and $|\Delta \phi_R(x)|\leq M/R^2$, then estimate
> $$\int_{\mathbb R} \phi_R |\nabla u|^2$$ in a way such that the right hand side goes to zero as $R \to \infty$.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to complete this proof, but it seems that it should work.

Answer (score 2):

$|\nabla u|$ is subharmonic because $\ |\nabla u|=\sup_{x\in S_p} |\partial_x u|$,let us write $\nabla u=v$.
$$
\int_{R^{n}}|v|^{2} d x=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \int_{\partial B_{r}(0)}|v(r, \theta)|^{2} d \theta d r
$$
by AM-GM inequality and $\|\cdot \|$ is a concave function and possion kernel expression, we have for $0\leq r_1\leq r_2<\infty$,
$$
\frac{1}{V(\partial B_{r_{2}}(b))}\int_{\partial B_{r_{2}}(b)}|v(r, \theta)|^{2} d \theta \geqslant \frac{1}{V(\partial B_{r_{1}}(b))}\int_{\partial B_{r_{1}(0)}}|v(r, \theta)|^{2} d \theta
$$
So $$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}|v|^{2} d x \geqslant \int_{0}^{+\infty}|v(0)|^{2} d r
\quad \quad (*)$$
In this argument 0 can change to any point $p\in \mathbb{R}^2$, so we proved $\forall p\in \mathbb{R}^2$, $v(p)=0$, so $v \equiv 0, \quad u \equiv \text { constant }$.

And you can take a $\phi_{R}$ Polished $(*)$ and prove $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi_{R}|\nabla u|^{2}<\infty$ imitate this.

Comment: Thank you! But I'd also like to avoid the mean value property. Is there any way to obtain a direct "energetic" proof of the result without it?

Comment: Sorry, my poor understanding of the harmonic function all comes from the average formula(or its variant, the Cauchy integral formula for holomorphic function), but I think there should have such proofs (probably not only one).